# using .replaceWith() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that has this elements:

```
<div id = "menu">

                <a>Elemento1</a><br/>

                <a>Elemento2</a><br/>

                <a>Elemento3</a><br/>

</div>
```

Each time one of the elements gets clicked I want a new div with different content to be added beside this list, depending on which element is clicked, it should add a diferent list. I'm new to web development, and I found that using the jQuery function `.replaceWith()` may do it, but is there any way I can use this function, adding divs I got in other .html files?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "other" .html files? jQuery only works on the currently-loaded HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a certain part of another HTML file, use [jQuery `load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function. A basic usage in your case, would be:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container_you_want_to_load');
```

To add an element after or before the link, you have a few choices. The question is if you really need it. Perhaps it's enough to define one target div into which you'll load your content. In that case, the above example would suit perfectly.

If you however want to add element next to `<a>` tag, consider using [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) jQuery functions.

To catch a click even on one of your links, check [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have `<div id="content"></div>` after the menu, then use
`$("#content").load("your_file.html");`?

Answer (score 1):

**replaceWith** is used to replace some DOM elements with different ones. I don't think this function can solve this.

You can use **.load** function to get html files content and insert it wherever you want. Just bind a click event to every link and use their **href** atributtes to get the respective file. Don't forget to **return false** in the end of the event.

something like this:

```
<div id="menu">
     <a href="page1.html">Elemento1</a>
     <a href="page2.html">Elemento2</a>
     <a href="page3.html">Elemento3</a>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>

$("#menu a").click(function(){
   $("#content").load(this.href);
   return false;
});
```